# Extract value from string php

Tags: php, extract

I have one string. This is the contains

```
-1--52--18-
```

I want to get this output

```
$Var1 = "1"
$Var2 = "52"
$Var3 = "18"
```

The number of variable is not fix (I can had beetween 1 and 3 values)
It is possible in PHP ?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just store the numbers on an array and not on individual variables?

Comment: Beacause i am not a expert in PHP and i am not know very well array and for each I preferred use if isset Var1 do This then if isset Var2 do This And if isset Var3 do This

Comment: https://3v4l.org/lT2Z8

Comment: Thanks for your awnser if you know a command for export all value of array in separate variables

Comment: https://3v4l.org/iQKEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array for this task. Especially, if you don't know how many vars you need.

```
$data = '-1--52--18-';
$vars = array_filter(explode('-', $data));
```

After you have everything in the array, you could use loops to iterate over the values or count/isset to check, if a value exists.

```
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    echo $var . "\n";
}
```

or

```
if (isset($var[0])) {
    // do sth. with var[0] = 1
}
```

If you need them inside var0 to var3, you could use `list`.

```
list($var0, $var1, $var2) = array_filter(explode('-', $data));
```

Or if you want this dynamically for what reason ever...

```
foreach ($vars as $index => $var) {
    ${"var" . $index} = $var;
}

echo $var0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it could be using [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

Then use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty entries and use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex the array from zero.

```
list($Var1, $Var2, $Var3) = array_values(array_filter(explode("-", "-1--52--18-")));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2j8UK)